# Google Mail missing in Cyanogenmod (gApps)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gmail

I installed Cyanogenmod and noticed that Google Mail is missing. I can't install it form the Market either. Market, Talk and so on are there, just Google Mail is missing.

How can I install Google Mail?

Comment: What version of CyanogenMod?

Comment: If you have a Titanium backup containing the apps, it's easy enough to restore... Go to menu, 'batch' operations, and scroll down to "restore".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be [a problem with the latest Cyanogenmod 7.1.0 and the german locale.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/kqpeq/gmail_app_incompatible_with_my_galaxy_s_in/) Possible solutions are

- Some users report that if you search google on your phone for "gmail market" and open the `market://` link with the Market, Gmail will install.
- Use the [market enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler&hl=en) to change your mobile provider and download the gmail app.
- Manually install [the .apk from this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=788992)

Answer (score 5):

Google does not provide some apps in the Market, since they're intended for "approved" devices (ones that meet Google's compatibility guidelines).  However, I believe they have a special agreement with CyanogenMod where you can flash the apps separately. You can read more about how to install these packages at ["How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score 1):

Install ROM Manager from the Market and then go to Download ROM, find Google Apps in the list and then you can choose the latest and install it. You can also see comments and ratings from other users.